# boto3 s3 role arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I can't use boto3 to connect to S3 with a role arn provided 100% programmatically.

```python
session = boto3.Session(role_arn="arn:aws:iam::****:role/*****",
                        RoleSessionName="****")

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id="****",
                         aws_secret_access_key="****")

for b in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print (b["Name"])
```

I can't provide arn info to Session and also client and there is no assume_role() on a client based on s3.

I found a way with a sts temporary token but I don't like that.

```python
sess = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id="*****",
                     aws_secret_access_key="*****")
sts_connection = sess.client('sts')
assume_role_object = sts_connection.assume_role(RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::***:role/******",
                                                RoleSessionName="**",
                                                DurationSeconds=3600)

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=assume_role_object['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=assume_role_object['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=assume_role_object['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

s3_client = session.client('s3')

for b in s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"]:
    print (b["Name"])
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: If boto3 doesn't provide you with a more concise way of creating a Session from an assumed role ARN, and it does not appear to, then you can write your own method to do it.

Comment: See: [Switching to an IAM Role (AWS API) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html)

Comment: @jarmod thanks , I will do that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how temporary credentials are created.

First you need to create a client using your current access keys. These credentials are then used to verify that you have the permissions to call assume_role and have the rights to issue credentials from the IAM role.

If someone could do it your way, there would be a HUGE security hole with assume_role. Your rights must be validated first, then you can issue temporary credentials.

Comment: I see , but I was looking for a single API call in the boto3 lib , anyway I will wrap the two calls , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *never* put an Access Key and Secret Key in your code. Always store credentials in a `~/.aws/credentials` file (eg via `aws configure`). This avoids embarrassing situations where your credentials are accidentally released to the world. Also, if you are running on an Amazon EC2 instance, then simply assign an IAM Role to the instance and it will automatically obtain credentials.

An easy way to assume a role in `boto3` is to store the role details in the credentials file with a separate **profile**. You can then reference the profile when creating a client and boto3 will automatically call `assume-role` on your behalf.

See: [boto3: Assume Role Provider](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider)

Comment: No it's for a function inside an airflow operator who need aws credentials programmatically.But thank for the advises.